# How can I create instances of a unity class in order to have multiple instances of the class running simultaneously w/o interrupting each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a city builder game and trying to create a crop growing system. This issue is with 2 different scripts, a placement manager and a farm timer. The placement manager class detects mousedown events and will setTile to my farm tilemap based off of the click location and the selected tile. The farm timer class contains a method which is called when a farm tile is set in the placement manager which then starts the timer using the update method to countdown from 60.

3 if statements check for 45, 30, and 15 seconds and calls another method in the placement manager which will set the tile to its respective growth stage tile. This works when only placing a single crop, but when there are multiple it starts the timer over with whichever tile was placed last.

I am guessing I need to find a way to create new instances of the class but I am also wondering if there would be a better way???

**PlacementManager.cs**

```cs
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isIndexSet)
    {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Location = farmGround.WorldToCell(pos);
        Location.z = 0;
        //6 is a carrot crop
        if(curIndex == 6 && isSpaceOpen())
        {
            PlacePlant();
            CurrencyManager.Instance.currency -= 1;
            //FarmTimer.instance.PlantPlaced("Carrot", Location);
            timer.PlantPlaced("Carrot", Location);
        }
        if(curIndex < 6 && isSpaceOpen())
        {
            PlaceBuilding();
            CurrencyManager.Instance.currency -= 5;
        }
    }
}
    
public void ChangePlantTile(int index, Vector3Int selectedLocation)
{
    farmPlants.SetTile(selectedLocation, plants[index]);
}
```

**FarmTimer.cs**

```cs
private string carrotChk1 = "Farm_36 (UnityEngine.Tilemaps.Tile)";
private string carrotChk2 = "Farm_35 (UnityEngine.Tilemaps.Tile)";
private string carrotChk3 = "Farm_34 (UnityEngine.Tilemaps.Tile)";

private int curIndex;
private bool isIndexSet = false;
public Tile[] tiles;
public Tile[] plants;
    
void Update()
{
    if (isTimerActive == true)
    { 
        if(plant == "Carrot")
        {
            CarrotTimer();
        }
    
    }
}
    
public void CarrotTimer()
{
    if (m_time < 45f && m_time > 30f 
        && FarmMap.GetTile(selectedLocation).ToString() != carrotChk1)
    {
        curIndex = 0;
        PlacementManager.Instance.ChangePlantTile(curIndex, selectedLocation);
        curIndex++;
    }
    else if (m_time < 15f && m_time > 1 
            && FarmMap.GetTile(selectedLocation).ToString() != carrotChk2)
    {
        PlacementManager.Instance.ChangePlantTile(curIndex, selectedLocation);
        curIndex++;
    }
    else if (m_time < 1f
            && FarmMap.GetTile(selectedLocation).ToString() != carrotChk3)
    {
        PlacementManager.Instance.ChangePlantTile(curIndex, selectedLocation);
        curIndex = 0;
        isTimerActive = false;
    }
}
```

For Testing purposes I am checking for the index of the carrot crop but I have 5 other crops which I plan to create the same functionality with.

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't comment... i will write here directly. If you don't like the answer just comment it i will delete it.

I think the only way you can do this is either:

1. create a class and store yout imer there.
2. create a scriptable object
3. maybe use some sort of 2D list in your farmTimer class. This List could contain a reference to the cell you planted, and an int variable to store the timer of this cell.
4. maybe you can use an interface.

I never used the 3rd method in unity.

For me the best option is either 1 or 2. The class would be easier to manage.

I hope it answer your question, have a great day !

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I am going to try instantiating new game objects whenever a crop is placed and then apply the script to the game object. Im not sure if this will mess up public variable assignments I have to the class but im hoping it will just make a new reference.

Comment: I tried turning farm timer into a scriptable object but im not sure how to implement that in a useful way for this situation. Any other suggestions/ explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure, i thinked about it for like 40min and i think scriptable objects are not what you need. Scriptable objects are used to store big amount of data at low performance cost. But the problem with them is that you can only get the value as they are read-only (they are made for the editor). I don't see how you could implement this.That was a bad idea from me :/. To my knowledge the only way is to create a class for your crops.

Comment: And in the last line of your post you said : _"I am guessing I need to find a way to create new instances of the class but I am also wondering if there would be a better way???"_ Is there a reason why you don't want to use classes ? I think it's the easiest.

Comment: Plus if your game have other type of plots i think it would be nice to implement some inheritance. You could have a base class with a variable for you cell (posX, posY), the name, etc... (everything that all your plots have in common). Then create a class for your crops wich inherit from your base class and contain a float "timer" (which will be separated for every instance). This way you will be less bothered to create other types of plots in the future. I definitely think it's the best option.

Comment: I hope i have been of any help.

Comment: So I tried your List method idea and that worked out! I have new indexs added to the list and it will continue to call the indexs on the list until the final growth phase and it will remove the index from the list. Then there are no indexs in the list the index counter will reset. Thank you very much the your reply it was very helpful!

Comment: No problem ! Don't forget to set your question to "resolved", have a nice day !